# Adding column to dataFrame

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I need to add new column to DataFrame (DynamicFrame) based on json data from other column, what's the best way to do it?

schema:

```
'id' 'name' 'customJson'
--------------------------
1 ,John, {'key':'lastName','value':'Smith'}
```

after:

```
'id' 'name' 'lastName' 'customJson'
-----------------------------------
1, John, Smith, {'key':'lastName','value':'Smith'}
```

Tried with withColumn but not sure how to fetch and calc data based on json value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DynamicFrames won't let you do this level of transformation, so you will need to cast it to PySpark DataFrame using `.toDF()` method then, after the transformation, `.fromDF()`.

Here is an example on how to parse it with PySpark DataFrame:

#### Creating a DataFrame as example

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame , SparkSession
spark = spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Parsing JSON") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1 ,"John", "{'key':'lastName','value':'Smith'}")],['id','name','customJson'])
```

#### Now Parsing the JSON Column

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json
schema = StructType([StructField('key', StringType()),StructField('value', StringType())])
 
df = df.select(
    df.id,
    df.name,
    from_json(df.customJson, schema).value.alias('lastName'),
    df.customJson
)
```

Feel free to run [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AvT1SBc1arzO0dPB41gbcxZf9SVs95Sl?usp=sharing) if you like.

Here is some documentation:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html

### [EDIT]

If your Json represents an array of elements (like in the comment below), you would need to include the `ArrayType` on schema, then use `explode` function to flatten out the values you need.

#### Creating DataFrame as example

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame , SparkSession
spark = spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local") \
    .appName("Word Count") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1 ,"John", "[{'key':'lastName','value':'Smith'},{'key':'lastName','value':'Silva'}]")],['id','name','customJson'])
```

#### Parsing Json representing array of elements

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, explode
schema = ArrayType(StructType([StructField('key', StringType()),StructField('value', StringType())]))
 
df = df.select(
    df.id,
    df.name,
    explode(
        from_json(df.customJson, schema)
    ).alias('parsedJson'),
    df.customJson
)

df.select(
    df.id,
    df.name,
    df.parsedJson.value.alias("lastName"),
).toPandas().to_markdown() 

# to_markdown properly formats the DataFrame as markdown to print below as table
```

|  | id | name | lastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | John | Smith |
| 1 | 1 | John | Silva |

Comment: Thanks! is it possible to extract columns if I have array of key, values, like "[{'key':'name', 'value':'John'},{'key':'name', 'value':'Jack'}]"

Comment: Wow, nice, this is some kung fu magic :), I just have one more question is it possible to set column name as 'key' value, so if I have multiple key values for example name, lastName I would get column 'name' and column 'lastName', that should be can column name be calculated like value?